# Presburger arithmetic and finite model property

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, presburger-arithmetic

I'm learning about model theory and first order logic. Recently, I read about finite model property and Presburger arithmetic, and I have two questions about them:

1. Does Presburger arithmetic has finite model property?
2. Given a Presburger formula. Clearly, it is SAT. Does it have finite number of models?

$$ \forall x.~ x>0 ~\wedge ~ y \ge 0 ~ \wedge ~ z \ge 0 ~ \wedge ~ x=y+z $$

Comment: I do not understand question 2. First, what do you mean by SAT? Second, do you mean a generic formula or the formula you write? Third, the formula you write is not a closed formula, so it makes to sense to speak about models of that formula. Moreover, as I read it, the formula you write implies $\forall x\ x>0$, so it never satisfied. Please, clarify.

Comment: Hi, for SAT, I mean "satisfiable" and my question 2 is for this particular formula. For your last point, I think you mean validity. This formula is invalid, but it is Satisfiable.

Comment: OK. Then the formula you write is not satisfiable. N.B. I read it as $\forall x\ \big[~ x>0 ~\wedge ~ y \ge 0 ~ \wedge ~ z \ge 0 ~ \wedge ~ x=y+z\big]$

Comment: See Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum, [Finite Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=jIFpliJXCw8C&pg=PA95) (2nd ed 1999) : **Ch.5. Satisfiabi!ity in the Finite**, page 95-on, for some results, e.g. : "any satisfiable universal sentence has a finite model."

Comment: If by *finite model property* for a class $\Phi$ of *sentences* we asks "whether every satisfiable sentence of $\Phi$ has a finite model", if $\Phi$ is the class of axioms of Presburger arithmetic, I think not : consider the domain with only $0$ and $1$. $1=s(0)$ but who is the successor of $1$ ? Not $0$, by axiom : $\forall x \lnot (0=s(x))$.

Comment: @PrimoPetri: yes, you are right. Sorry, I didn't check carefully.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: By "an universal sentence", do you think that it means a sentence just contains at least one universal quantifier? For your second comment, do you mean that $\forall x, neg(0 = s(x))$ has infinite number of models? For me, this formula is Valid, but it doesn't have free variables, so I don't what is its model.

Comment: 1) a *sentence* is a formula with **no** free variables. Thus 2) an *universal* sentence is a sentence with only $\forall$ in front. $\forall x \lnot (x=0)$ is an universal sentence; it is the first axiom of Presburger (and Robinson and Peano) arithmetic. "What is" a model for it ? It is a *domain* (not empty) with a "designated" element (the element referenced by $0$) and a *function* (the interpretation of $s$) that satisfy the axiom. Thus the domain must contain the successor of $0$ that cannot be $0$ itself : call it $1$, and must contain the successor of $1$, that cannot be $0$, 1/2

Comment: ... by first axiom, and cannot be $1$ because otherwise, by second axiom : $s(1)=1=s(0)$ and thus $0=1=s(0)$ again contradicting the axiom. And so on. 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thanks for correcting me. I think that I understand your point. I have one more question regarding "any satisfiable universal sentence has a finite model". Because it is about universal sentence, that mean there is no free variables (closed formula), and no models. So, is this the case that no models is also considered as finite model?

Comment: I do not understand why you are saying that a *sentence* (i.e. a "closed" formula) has no model. $1+1=2$ (i.e. $s(0)+s(0)=s(s(0))$) is provable from Presburger (and Peano) axioms; thus, it is true in any model of those axioms...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Yes, you are right. And if so, I think that the formula is true in any model, thus it has an infinite number of models. But why did the book write that "any satisfiable universal sentence has a finite model."? This statement still confuses me. (Btw, thank you very much for discussing with me)

Comment: You are saying : "has an infinite number of models" ... But *finite model property* means "to have a *finite* model", i.e. that there is a structure satisfying the axioms or the sentence that has a finite number of elements. The two things are not the same ...

Comment: I am clear now! Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Sebastian: Can you explain more about your question?